# SVG Scaling and viewBox

Tags: svg

Here is a simple SVG file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100mm" height="100mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 377.95 377.95">
  <rect x="0" width="189" height="189" stroke="black" stroke-width="6" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

This renders a 100mm x 100mm box with the top left corner at the origin as expected.

If I change the viewbox to:

```
 viewBox="0 0 177.95 177.95"
```

then the box is scaled up, still with the top left corner at the origin, as expected.

However, if I change only the width of the view box like so:

```
  viewBox="0 0 177.95 377.95"
```

then then box is *not* scaled but *is* moved along the X axis.

I thought only the first two parameters of the viewbox affected the translation? Also why isn't the box stretched in the X direction?

Does the viewbox scaling only work correctly if the scaling is the same in both X and Y directions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the viewport is scaled in actual dimensions (embed frame) of the SVG is governed by `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

See [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) and/or refer too [Understanding SVG Coordinate Systems and Transformations](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) by Sara Soueidan.